# How to return custom posts in loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

How to Return Custom Posts in Loop? I read couple of articles about the same topic but nothing straight forward. I have a blog that show the regular posts and I have custom posts 'advert'. I like to start showing latest custom posts in loop. The end result can be loop that returns custom posts only.

```
 <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="post-0" class="post not-found item-list">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'tie' ); ?></h2>
    <div class="entry">
        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the  requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>

  <?php else : ?>
   <?php
  $count = 0;
  $post_width = tie_post_width();
  $exc_home_cats = tie_get_option( 'exc_home_cats' );
if( is_home() && $exc_home_cats ) query_posts( array(  'advert','category__not_in' => $exc_home_cats , 'paged' => $paged) ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;
$color = '';
$get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$tie_post_color = $get_meta["tie_post_color"][0];
if( !empty($tie_post_color)) $color ='custom-color '.$tie_post_color;
?>  

<article <?php post_class('item-list post rtl-item '.$color.' '.$post_width) ?>>
    <div class="post-inner">            
        <?php 
            $format = get_post_format();
            if( false === $format ) { $format = 'standard'; }
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', $format ); ?>


</article><!-- .item-list -->


<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: what is the result of this code ?

Comment: The result should be the latest posts for the custom post called 'advert'

Comment: I added the custom post 'advert' in my code above but still returning regular posts.

Comment: I think adding global $post;
 $orig_post = $post; might help

Comment: try with `"post_type" => 'advert'`

Comment: Didn't work still showing regular posts.

Answer (score 0):

The following code Worked with the code above:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'yourposttypehere', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
The stuff you want to loop goes in here
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Source: [link](https://wp-agency.co.uk/wordpress-loop-custom-post-type/)